# Vim configuration, setting up autocomplete, and columns

Tags: vim, editor

1. How do I set up auto-completion for C? I've heard it's language agnostic. How does this work?
2. Where can I find a list of settings available for vim?
3. I often find that code is usually occupying the left side of my screen when editing.
   How can I have the next "page" or so of code displayed on the right side, treating the column on the right side as just an extension what's on the left side, with the two scrolling together nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You usually don't need to set anything up, as far as I can recall.  Try typing the beginning of an identifier (or any other word) and hitting `Ctrl+n` (still in insert mode).  It will pop up a list of possible completions, or just complete it if there is only one.  The places this searches for possible matches are configurable.  Try `:help i_ctrl-n` for details.  One of the places it searches by default is the tags file, which you may want to read up on, as that's a very useful feature (`:help tags`).

2) Vim has a very good help system available by typing `:help` in command mode.

3) I don't know if this is possible, perhaps someone else can help you with it.

Comment: 3. I think http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns will work pretty well. Thank you!