# Emacs follow-mode with multiple splits

Tags: emacs, split, elisp

My question is related to the following two:
[Emacs - Multiple columns one buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970292/emacs-multiple-columns-one-buffer)
[Vim configuration, setting up autocomplete, and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588706/vim-configuration-setting-up-autocomplete-and-columns)

I'm using MPage now in vim, and it works well even when I have more than two columns. How can I use follow-mode to mimic that behavior in Emacs, and have flowing code in more than two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow-mode flows into however many columns you have, by default